How can I get a container to fill the width of the iPad Pro Screen skin when other skins work correctly?
I have a design screen and a playback screen for my plays. I turned on the iPad Pro skin to check the resize, and one stretches as it should and the other doesn't. I have used the same code to build both forms and containers.

Would you edit into your question a small example of the code that you are having trouble with? The editor supports Markdown formatting.

As I copied the code to edit the answer I saw I had added a Container to put the field Container in. I removed that extra Container, and the 2 screens are displaying the same on the 13" skin in the Simulator. I will keep working with it to see if the odd behavior comes back.
